# `which` isn't showing the executable that actutally runs

Tags: macos, shell

```
macmini:bin hindlet$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
macmini:bin hindlet$ /usr/local/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.7.4
macmini:bin hindlet$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.6
```

Even though `which` is telling me that the python3 in `/usr/local/bin/python3` is in my path first, that's not what runs when I type `python3`. Instead it runs the one in `/usr/bin`

So I'd expect `which` to tell which which program will run when I type the program name.

My Path:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin:/Users/hindlet/Library/Python/2.7/bin/"
```

Comment: Does `command -v python3` give the same result as `which python3`?

Comment: [Why not use `which`? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/108618)

Comment: "command -v python3 " -> "/usr/bin/python3"

Comment: I haven't fully read and comprehended the in depth answer yet, but I think gist of it is don't use `which`. so yes I think so. thanks. (which doesn't appear to consider to hashed commands)